# Best Practices / Lessons Learned for Migrating to Snowflake from SQL Server or DB2

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anyone have a list of Best Practices or Lessons Learned for migrating to Snowflake from SQL Server or DB2?

We're learning as we go but are discovering that some things don't work the same (we expected some learnings).  Examples: Primary Key Constraints not being enforced; CAST of varchar to a shorter field is a hard error vs a warning so ETL process abends.

I have not found documentation (other than generic recommendations on planning and some good recommendations around data loads) but limited info on ETL practices.

Comment: partitioning is completely different concept in SF

Comment: If you don't get good answers here, you can try https://reddit.com/r/snowflake too (more oriented to discussion than Stack Overflow, which is better for specific questions)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa - thanks for that - I did not think to look on Reddit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide might help you get started:

https://resources.snowflake.com/migration-guides/microsoft-sql-server-to-snowflake-migration-reference-manual